# Show link name in div and change background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show the name of the "choose a Brand" in a div("Chosen brand") after selecting the menu and at the same time change the background image from the site also. So if someone clicks on a brand like BMW it must show the name "BMW" in the "choosed brand" div and change the background image from the Website.

For Example please have a look at the site: [Car select](http://ulli.ddns.net)

I use the following script to fill the select options

```js
var selectData = {

  "bmw": {

    "1": "316i",
    "100": "520i",
    "101": "740i"

  },
  "audi": {
    "2": "Audi A4",
    "200": "AudiA6",
    "201": "AudiA8"

  },
  "mercedes": {

    "3": "A 180",
    "300": "E 320",
    "301": "S 500"

  },

};
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', '.specialLink', function(event) {

    var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2');
    if (radio2.checked == false) {
      radio2.checked = true;
      toggleRadio();
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    var b = $(this),
      buttonId = b.attr('id'),
      selectSet = selectData[buttonId],
      selectField = $('#specialLink');
    selectField.empty();
    if (selectSet) {
      $.each(selectSet, function(k, v) {
        selectField.append($('<option>', {
          value: k,
          text: v
        }));
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and for Toggling this script

```js
function toggleRadio() { // will activate when the form will change.
  var radio1 = document.getElementById('radio1'); // radio 1
  var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2'); // radio 2
  if (radio1.checked == true) { // if the first checked display input and hide select
    document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('specialLink').value = ''; // clear selected option
  } else { // because i got only 2 option i don't have to use another condition
    document.getElementById('textLabel').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('selectLabel').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('textin').value = ''; // clear input
  }
}
toggleRadio(); // call the function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some change in the above code to get the desired result. As you can see I have added an image index into the selectedData object on top just to get the respective background image of a brand. I have mentioned the code changes into comments as well.

```
var selectData = {

  "bmw":{

        "1":"316i",
         "100":"520i",
          "101":"740i",
          "image":"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg"
  },
  "audi":{
    "2":"Audi A4",
    "200":"AudiA6",
     "201":"AudiA8",
     "image":"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg"

  },
   "mercedes":{

         "3":"A 180",
         "300":"E 320",
          "301":"S 500",
          "image":"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg"

  },

 };
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(document).on('click', '.specialLink', function(event) {
        var radio2 = document.getElementById('radio2');
        if (radio2.checked == false) {
          radio2.checked = true;
          toggleRadio();
        }
        $(".brand").html($(this).text());
        event.preventDefault();
        var b = $(this),
        background_image = '';
          buttonId = b.attr('id'),
          selectSet = selectData[buttonId],
          selectField = $('#specialLink');
        selectField.empty();
        //To change the background image of website
        $("#banner").css('background','url("'+selectSet.image+'")');
        if (selectSet) {
        //Remove imgae index form selectSet
         $.each(selectSet, function(k, v) {
        if(typeof k === 'string' && k === 'image') {
        return true; } selectField.append($('<option>', 
        { value: k, text: v })); 
        });
        }
        return false;
      });
    });
```

Comment: Yes, that work nearly perfect, but its work only one time with the background change. If click again some link used already it will show a white background.I put your code in the website you can try again please.

Comment: Ohh I see, instead of deleting an element from the selectset array we can just skip that image index and its value.
Remove or comment following code delete selectSet['image']; from above script and add the below code into jquery each selectset function.

         $.each(selectSet, function(k, v) {
           if(typeof k === 'string' && k === 'image') {
            return true;
           }
           selectField.append($('<option>', {
              value: k,
              text: v
            }));
          });

Comment: Great, that works verry well. Now i see that the "media screen" in the css no more working. I have 5 media screen for diffrent display size for the background image.  .                                                                                                                            @media screen and (max-width: 1780px){
.banner{

media screen and (max-width: 1080px)
media screen and (max-width: 1050px)
media screen and (max-width: 991px)
media screen and (max-width: 480px)

Comment: @bruno2000, I have seen your media query and I found it's not working at all. You just need to add some more style to make background-image responsive. Just copy below code and adds it to your CSS. 

.banner { background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain; background-position:center; } 

Along with this change above script code : $("#banner").css('background','url("'+selectSet.image+'")'); to $("#banner").css('background-image','url("'+selectSet.image+'")');

Comment: is it possible to write like this in the script?  "bmw":{

        "1":"316i",
         "100":"520i",
          "101":"740i",
          "image":"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg"                                                                         if ($(window).width() < 641) { 
$("#Banner").attr("src", "images/BG700px.jpg")  ,   if ($(window).width() < 900) { 
$("#Banner").attr("src", "images/BG900px.jpg") ,   if ($(window).width() < 1200) { 
$("#Banner").attr("src", "images/BG1200.jpg")

Comment: Yes, you can write in that way. Then you must have to call your $(window).width() method inside jquery window resize function. 

For instance :

$(window).resize(function() {
  var descTop = $(window).width()
if (descTop < 826){
       $("#Banner").attr("src", "images/BG900px.jpg");
}
});

Comment: @bruno2000, I don't think this approach will work perfectly and efficiently. There might be some issue in future when you will add some more media screen on your webpage, So in that scenario, you have to change selectedData object and JS script code too. I would suggest you keep your JS script code immutable(No need to change for each case) so that you can achieve your desired result by writing less code. Please reconsider my 2nd comment to be the solution of this particular question.

Comment: .banner{
background:url(../images/baner1920.jpg) 0px 0px  no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
min-height:520px;
-webkit-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
 }                                                                                  @media screen and (max-width: 1780px){
.banner{
background:url(../images/baner1776.jpg) 0px 0px  no-repeat;}}                   how the script now which file have to load for the media screen

Comment: Try with below CSS .banner{ 
 background:url(../images/baner1920.jpg) 0px 0px no-repeat; 
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:contain; 
 background-position:center;
 min-height:520px; 
 -webkit-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out; 
 -moz-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out; 
 -o-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out; 
 transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out; 
} . This might help you get rid out of this. Script won't do anything with media screen, its take your default css which is loaded by your browser and make your website responsive.

Comment: [link to Site](http://ulli.ddns.net/web) i have update the website with the code you wrote. Please have a look on the site. When the site start, the background is Responsiv over the media screens, the diffrent window size have diffrent background files. When the background change first time with the script it cant load the media screen files with diffrent size. Mayby now you can understand my problem.

Comment: @bruno2000 Is it necessary to load different image for their respective window sizes. I mean you can load a single image for their respective background and make it responsive. As I have gone through your website it works fine after changing the background image also.

Comment: Yes, the site works, but for tablet or smartphone users I would like to use specially adapted backgrounds and provide them via the media screens. So my idea to do it with the list: var selectData = {
  "Bmw": {
         "1": "316i"
          "100", "520i"
           "101", "740i"
           "Image1": "images / 640px.jpg"
           "Image2": "images / 900px.jpg"
   },
   $ ("# banner MEDIA SCREEN 640px"). css ('background', 'url ("' + selectSet.image1 + '")');$ ("# banner MEDIA SCREEN 900px"). css ('background', 'url ("' + selectSet.image2 + '")');

Comment: @bruno2000Okay, then instead of changing the background URL change it's to background-image in your media screen banners. I hope it will work as you expected.

Comment: i have try this but it will not work.                                                                          $("@media screen and (max-width: 480px)").css('background-image','url("'+selectSet.image1+'")');         i dont no how write the banner in this line?

Answer (score 0):

To change the text, set the `.textContent` of the ""Choosed brand""-div in your clickhandler on ".specialLink"  to `$(this).text()`.

To change the color, you can set `element.style.background` of your target element to the desired color, again in your clickhandler.

Comment: can you show me how to look have the div and where i have to edit the select option script?

Comment: you could add the desired actions below the following line `$(document).on('click', '.specialLink', function(event) {`. you can figure out the divs handle by right clicking it in a browser and inspecting it (I believe it has a class of brand so the selector'd be $('.brand'))